# The addClass(green) only works once

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make the whole div green when the result number is greater than 10 and otherwise, red. When I put two numbers that makes the result less than 10, it is red, but when I change to greater than 10, it is still red. The green only works when enter numbers after refreshing the page.

```js
$(document).ready(startApp);

function startApp() {
  /*
      add a click handler to the button that calls the function below on click
  */
  function doCalculation() {
    var number1 = Number($('#number1').val());
    var number2 = Number($('#number2').val());
    var result = number1 + number2;
    if (result > 10) {
      $('#display').addClass('highText');
      $('#display span').text(result);
    } else {
      $('#display').addClass('lowText');
      $('#display span').text(result);
    }

  }
  $('#doIt').on('click', doCalculation);

}
/*
    make a function that does the following:
        get the numbers from #number1 and #number2
        add the numbers together
        place the result into the span INSIDE the #display element
        extra:
        if the number > 10, make the entire #display element text green
        otherwise, make it red with the classes above
    
    
    */
```

```css
.highText {
  color: green;
}

.lowText {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="number1" placeholder="1st number"> +
<input type="text" id="number2" placeholder="2nd number">
<div id="display">result--- <span></span></div>
<button id="doIt">calculate!</button>
```

Comment: you're not removing the previously added class

Answer (score 1):

That's because you end up with both classes applied and the red class is applied last, overruling the green class. Solution? Remove all the classes first with `$('#display').removeClass()`:

```js
$(document).ready(startApp);

function startApp() {
  /*
      add a click handler to the button that calls the function below on click
  */
  function doCalculation() {
    var number1 = Number($('#number1').val());
    var number2 = Number($('#number2').val());
    $('#display').removeClass();
    var result = number1 + number2;
    if (result > 10) {
      $('#display').addClass('highText');
      $('#display span').text(result);
    } else {
      $('#display').addClass('lowText');
      $('#display span').text(result);
    }

  }
  $('#doIt').on('click', doCalculation);

}
/*
    make a function that does the following:
        get the numbers from #number1 and #number2
        add the numbers together
        place the result into the span INSIDE the #display element
        extra:
        if the number > 10, make the entire #display element text green
        otherwise, make it red with the classes above
    
    
    */
```

```css
.highText {
  color: green;
}

.lowText {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="number1" placeholder="1st number"> +
<input type="text" id="number2" placeholder="2nd number">
<div id="display">result--- <span></span></div>
<button id="doIt">calculate!</button>
```

Comment: Not sure about the advisability of removing all classes, just remove the ones that are relevant.

Comment: @Barmar For this example it's fine. But if the user needs to worry about it, they'd just replace `$('#display').removeClass()` with `$('#display').removeClass('highText lowText')`

Comment: but if the next result is greater than 10, doesn't it add the green class at the end, which overrule the red class before

Comment: @WeilinHong You don't need both classes on the div at any time. Only add the one that applies with removeClass()